# Processing accessing specific location of pixel in random Array

Tags: arrays, graph, processing

I have random ellipses been drawn in rows sequentially across 7 columns. However, instead of randomly drawing the number of ellipses anywhere within the row array I would like to only draw them so one of the ellipses in column one must touch one of the ellipses in column two etc. So that there are no gaps between positions. The end visual looking like a bar graph animating at different bar heights but using an array of ellipses to do so. Similar to this image.
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXSGS.jpg)

My working code is below. Would I move to accessing the pixel colour value and doing an 'if condition' to compare if rowArray[i] is next to a black pixel or is there a simpler method I'm overlooking here? All help appreciated. Thanks.

```java
PImage pix = createImage(7, 7, RGB);
int counter = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
int rowArray[ ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int colArray[ ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int frameDelay = 300; //pause 400 ms between frames being sent to the board
float dot = 0;
int count;

void setup() {

  background(0);
  size(500, 500);
  dot = height/7.0;



  pix.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < pix.pixels.length; i++) {
    pix.pixels[i] = color(0);
  }
  pix.updatePixels();
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(CORNER);
}

void draw() {

  //boolean dot = false;
  //randomSeed(0);
  pix.loadPixels();



  if (counter > pix.height) {
    counter = 0;
    y ++;
  }

  if (counter2 > pix.width) {
    counter2 = 0;
    x ++;
    //also refesh screen after one round
    refresh();
  }

  //reset-don't go beyond pixel boundaries
  if (x > pix.width) {
    x = 0;
  }
  if (y > pix.height) {
    y = 0;
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < pix.width; j++) {
    if (j==counter2) {
      for (int i = 0; i < pix.height; i++) {
        if (i == counter) {

          //random height

          i = int(random(rowArray.length));  // Same as int(random(i))
          y=i;
          x=j;
          //draw the white circles
          stroke(64);
          strokeWeight(1);
          fill(255);
          noStroke();
          ellipse(x*dot, y*dot, dot, dot);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  counter++;
  counter2++;



  pix.updatePixels();

  pix.loadPixels();



  delay (frameDelay);
}
void refresh() {

  background(0);
}
```

/*EDIT!!!!!*/
I have streamlined my code as it had some unnecessary for loops. Now using pixel [loc] to determine the location of white and black pixels and go from there.

EDITED CODE

```java
PImage pix = createImage(7, 7, RGB);
int counter = 0;
//int randCount=0;
int counter2 = 0;
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
//int randCount[ ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int randCount[ ] =  new int[7];
//int rowArray[ ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

int frameDelay = 300; //pause 400 ms between frames being sent to the board
float dotSize = 0;


void setup() {

  background(0);
  size(500, 500);
  dotSize = height/7.0;


  //make all dots black on start
  pix.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < pix.pixels.length; i++) {
    pix.pixels[i] = color(0);
  }
  pix.updatePixels();
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(CORNER);
}

void draw() {

  //  boolean dot = false;

  pix.loadPixels();
  //bitshift values from array
  int row1 = 0;
  int row2 = 0;
  int row3 = 0;
  int row4 = 0;
  int row5 = 0;
  int row6 = 0;
  int row7 = 0;


  //randomise how many dots are displayed in the row
  int index = int(random(randCount.length));
  counter=index;

  if (counter > pix.height) {
    counter = 0;
    y ++;
  }

  if (counter2 > pix.width) {
    counter2 = 0;
    x ++;
  }


  //reset-don't go beyond pixel boundaries
  if (x > pix.width) x = 0;
  if (y > pix.height) y = 0;

  //sequence dots row by row 
  for (int i = 0; i < pix.height; i++) {
    if (i == counter) {

      //y is i
      y=i;

      //draw the white circles representing flipdots
      stroke(64);
      strokeWeight(1);
      fill(255);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x*dotSize, y*dotSize, dotSize, dotSize);
    }
  }
  if (x==7) {
    //also refesh screen after one round
    refresh();
  }

  counter++;
  counter2++;
  detect();


  pix.updatePixels();

  pix.loadPixels();



  delay (frameDelay);
}


//screen refresh
void refresh() {

  background(0);
  y=0;
  x=0;
}

void detect() {
  //pixel location
  int loc = x + y*pix.height;

  // Pixel to the left location and color
  int leftLoc = (x - 1) + y*pix.width;

  // Pixel to the right location and color
  int rightLoc = (x + 1) + y*pix.width;

  // Pixel to the left location and color
  int downLoc = (x - 1) + y*pix.height;

  // Pixel to the right location and color
  int upLoc = (x + 1) + y*pix.height;

  //is the pixel white?
  if ((pix.pixels[loc]==255)&&(pix.pixels[leftLoc]==255)&&(pix.pixels[rightLoc]==255)&&(pix.pixels[downLoc]==255)&&(pix.pixels[upLoc]==255)) {
    y++;
    // x++;
  } else {
    y--;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. It's really hard to help with general "how do I do this" type questions. You'll have much better luck if you ask a specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take on those pieces one at a time. Then if you get stuck on a specific piece, you can post a [mcve] of just that piece. Good luck.

Comment: A good lesson in improving the phrasing of my question. Sorry I took for granted the stages I had covered on my own and how that translates when posted on here.                                                                                                     Based on your advice I have broken down my working in the answer below (due to limited characters in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT -it is now solved.Code posted below in case anyone else encounters similar troubleshooting.

Based on the advice above I have reworded the question:

I have tried creating a randomised array length and looping through this array to draw random x amount ellipses in a row. This visually translates to a series of white ellipses at differing heights like a bar graph.                                                                   The minimal code below loops through the array length and successfully draws an ellipse at each pixel in the array length sequentially. This is what I want. However, because it is randomised it sometimes leaves a gap(a black pixel) between the ellipses. For example, in row 1 it may draw 3 white ellipses in sequence and then a gap of 1 pixel then a 4th ellipse in the length. I am trying to remove the  'gap'.                                                            This code achieves the 'one ellipse after another draw sequence' I am aiming for but has the black gaps in creating ellipses along the array length.

```java
PImage pix = createImage(7, 7, RGB);
int counter = 0;
//int randCount=0;
int counter2 = 0;
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
int lastY=0;
//int randCount[ ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int randCount[ ] =  new int[7];
int rowArray[ ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int colArray[]= new int[7];
int frameDelay = 500; //pause 400 ms between frames being sent to the board
float dotSize = 0;


void setup() {

  background(0);
  size(500, 500);
  dotSize = height/7.0;


  //make all dots black on start
  pix.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < pix.pixels.length; i++) {
    pix.pixels[i] = color(0);
  }
  pix.updatePixels();
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(CORNER);
}

void draw() {



  pix.loadPixels();


  //here do sequential index plus a random value
  // for(int j = 0; j < rowArray.length; j++){

  //randomise how many dots are displayed in the row
  int index = int(random(randCount.length));

  //counter=index;

  //if beyond pixel boundaries
  if (counter > pix.height) {
    counter = 0;
    y ++;
  }

  if (counter2 > pix.width) {
    counter2 = 0;
    x ++;
  }


  //reset-don't go beyond pixel boundaries
  if (x > pix.width) x = 0;
  if (y > pix.height) y = 0;

  //sequence dots row by row 

  //loop through the randomised array lengths.  
  for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {



    // if dot is within boundary and sequencial.  
    if (i == counter) {

      //y is i. height is i.
      y=i;


      //draw the white circles representing flipdots
      stroke(64);
      strokeWeight(1);
      fill(255);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x*dotSize, y*dotSize, dotSize, dotSize);
    }
  }


  if (x==7) {
    //also refesh screen after one round
    refresh();
  }

  counter++;
  counter2++;



  pix.updatePixels();

  pix.loadPixels();



  //time between dot animations
  delay (frameDelay);
}


//screen refresh
void refresh() {

  background(0);
  y=0;
  x=0;
}
```

I recognised the issue lies with how the for loops are constructed. I have then tried the following structure of for loop which solves the 'pixel gap'
by adding a second for loop sequencing through the entire pixel height then minus-ing the random length by the pixel.height length. This now works.

```java
  //sequence dots row by row 

  //loop through the randomised array lengths.  
  for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {

  for (int j=0; j<index; j++) {

    // if dot is within boundary and sequencial.  
    if (i == counter) {

      //y is i. height is i.
      y=i-j;


      //draw the white circles representing flipdots
      stroke(64);
      strokeWeight(1);
      fill(255);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x*dotSize, y*dotSize, dotSize, dotSize);
    }
  }
  }
```

Therefore, I am continuing to try to solve the construction of my for loops that draw a random length of ellipses but without any gaps between that length in the row. I hope that is clearer and more in line with how to construct a question on the forum. 
Thanks

Comment: If your question is solved, you might want to mark this answer as correct.